# How to consume api rest using TurboGears2?

Tags: python-requests, turbogears2

I want to show the data in the view

```
r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
print(r)
print(r.headers)
print(r.encoding)
data = r.json()
log.debug(data)
log.debug(r)

for post in data:
 s = format(post["id"],post['title'])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your web-app create a controller having `@expose('json')` as the decorator and then you can request that url the way you want. While requesting the url you may want to append `.json` at the end of the url. For example in your case

```
@expose('json')
def posts(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #do your stuff
    return dict(data=data)
```

and then you can easily call this url.

```
r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.json')
```